# C# Error- Small console app

Tags: c#

I'm still trying to get the hang of this. The second part of my Main method will not execute. I believe I've called it correctly. But, obviously I didn't. A little help would be greatly appreciated!

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Threading;

namespace mellon_Assignment2
{
    class Getting2KnowUapp
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            WriteLine("The current time is: " + DateTime.Now);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            AboutMe Me = new AboutMe();

        }
    }
}



using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Threading;

namespace mellon_Assignment2
{
    class AboutMe
    {
        public void DisplayInfo()
        {
            WriteLine("My Name\tAssignment 2");
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            WriteLine("ITDEV110\tIntro to Object-oriented Programming");
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            WriteLine("Professor\tSeptember 18th");
            Thread.Sleep(1500);    
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't invoke `Me.DisplayInfo()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echoing the other replies, you aren't invoking the method on your class.

If you want it to occur when you create a new instance, you could move it into the constructor.

To do that, change:

```
public void DisplayInfo()
```

to

```
 public AboutMe()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `DisplaInfo` method. You are only creating the object and doing nothing with it:

```
AboutMe Me = new AboutMe();
Me.DisplayInfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

`public void DisplayInfo()` is it's own method and has to be called directly after initialization of the class `AboutMe`.

If you want the `DisplayInfo()` method to fire immediately upon initialization of `AboutMe` then simply add a constructor for `AboutMe` like so.

```
class AboutMe {
    public AboutMe() {
      DisplayInfo();
    }    

     public void DisplayInfo() {
     ...
     }
}
```

Then you can call:
`AboutMe myvariable = new AboutMe();`